# How to make array of data as Key of Database Child

Tags: swift, firebase

Previously, I wanted to query my array data in my Firebase, but I found that query is not support in array data in firebase. Therefore, I want to make my array as key with the value being true. Thank you in advance.

For example,
when I have the `array = ["a", "b", "c"]`

I want to change it as

```
subject
-------"a":"true"
-------"b":"true"
-------"c":"true"
```

Comment: If you want to store such data in firebase, a better way is to make a child. This child has 2 children, one that stores true/false and another child stores array and you also consume less space.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's being asked is how to take an array of strings as shown in the question and write them to Firebase where each string element is a key and it has a child value of true.

We can leverage a Swift Dictionary's *uniqueKeysWithValues* function to create key: value pairs and store them in a dictionary which can then be written to Firebase.

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: array.map { ($0, true) })
fbRef.child("subject").setValue(dict)
```

and the result will be

```
subject
   a: true
   b: true
   c: true
```

Another option is to create an extension to add functionality to arrays (a sequence).

```
extension Sequence {
    func toDictionary() -> [String: Bool] {
        var dict = [String: Bool]()
        for element in self {
            if let s = element.self as? String {
                dict[s] = true
            }
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
let anArray = ["x", "y", "z"]
let dict = anArray.toDictionary()
fbRef.child("subject").setValue(dict)
```

This could use more error checking and assumes the elements are always strings.